# getting ping in ms in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping, raspbian

I need a way to get ping in ms but the only thing i can find is that pinging in rasbian only returns a 0 if the servers up but i need ping in milliseconds

Comment: What did you do so far? You can do the same thing via the command line by typing sudo ping <your server>.

Comment: `import os; os.system('ping google.com')`

Comment: @bhazero025 i tried response = os.system('ping -c 1 google.com')

Comment: Not quite. You don't need python for this. Just open your terminal and type sudo ping www.google.com

Comment: @bhazero025 im trying to get the ping for a program im working on

Comment: To collect the result of _ping_ command, you may use subprocess.Popen, e.g. `proc = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 google.com", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`, and then `(out, err) = proc.communicate()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.system("ping abc.xyz")
```